# Standard deviation, return on investment , probability

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

In current year companies in the market have an average return on investment of 12.8% and standard deviation of return is 3.2%. Average return is normally distributed. What is the probability that a random selected company in the market will have a return of investment that is within one standard deviation of the average of the return on investment in the market?

Comment: You can just use the Empirical Rule: roughly 68%.